# Modeling iterative processes in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

In the QGIS version 2.X, there was an Iterative Button from the algorithm also available for the algorithm used inside the processing modeller.

Actually, I use version 3.2 and 3.4 and can not find it. Will I find the button somewhere else or is the iterative button removed?

[image: Example_1]

[image: Example_2]

Comment: Hi AndreasR welcome to Stack Exchange. I don't quite understand your question. A screenshot of the button in QGIS 2.X might make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Which algorithm?

Comment: Specially the intersection algorithm.

Comment: [![Dialog from QGIS 3.10.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWEMu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWEMu.png) Please note:, there is also no 'selected features only' checkbox.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the **Vector Features** input parameter if you want to iterate over ***all*** or ***selected*** features:

[image: Example model iterating features]

Now when you run the model, you can choose whether to run the model once on all or selected features and return a single output; or iterate over all or selected features and return an output per feature:

[image: Running iterate model]

Comment: Thanks a lot , sometimes it is like: "can´t see the wood for the trees".

Comment: @AndreasR - Most welcome and don't worry, there's been a lot of changes in QGIS 3 compared to 2 so it does take getting used to finding where everything is again :)

Comment: The problem persists. The 'iterate' button that appears in the 'Example3' dialog you show above does not appear in 3.10.3, or the latest LTR (3.10.12) . It is as AndreasR states. Currently checking whether it appears in 3.16.1. There is also no 'selected features only' option.  What version of QGIS does your 'Example3' dialog come from, please?  Both ITERATE and SELECTED FEATURES ONLY  appear in 3.16